# Deleting 5% of width every time the button is clicked JS

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I don't know how to write a simple event listener to delete 5% od elements width every time the button is clicked. From 100% to 0%.

```
substracktBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    container.style.width = "calc(" + container.style.width + " - 5%)";
})
```

In this code i got no errors but the div's width is still 100% after the clicks.

Comment: Do you want to remove 5% of the elements initial width, which will be constant, or remove 5% of it's current width (which will be a different width each time.)

Comment: Right, i didn't think about that the width will be different every time... I want everytime to delete 5% of the beggining width, not the current.

Comment: Is the element's width set as `100%` in CSS. Is the container a block level or inline element? Could do with seeing relevant CSS and HTML too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your solution:

- It will **remove 5% of the beginning width each time** till you reach 0%. With the other solution you will never get to 0% because you always take the 5% of the current width.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('div')
const button = document.querySelector('button')
const subtractPerClick = container.offsetWidth * 0.05

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (container.offsetWidth - subtractPerClick > 0)
    container.style.width = container.offsetWidth - subtractPerClick + 'px'
  else
    container.style.width = '0px'
})
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<button>Substract</button>
```

Comment: It works great but unfrotunately stops at 5%, not 0%.

Comment: @KolekcjaKolekcja Works now! The bug was that when the last subtraction is a negativ width it won't update the width since you can not have an negative width. Now it checks before.

Comment: @KolekcjaKolekcja Just in general what is the width of your container? Is it dynamic? What's the lowest?

Comment: Now it works perfectly. Thank you. The starting width is 80vw of the body container that has 100vw.

Comment: Okay that should work. The problem is that if the box is so small that 5% of the beginning width is less than 1px it will not get smaller. (It will remove 0px each time) If you need a fix for that as well just reply again.

Answer (score 1):

For removing 5% of the current width. This converges!

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  container.style.width = container.offsetWidth * 0.95 + 'px'
})
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>

<button id="button">Substract</button>
```

For removing 5% of the starting width

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const button = document.getElementById('button');

let startWidth5Percent = container.offsetWidth * 0.05;

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
   container.style.width = container.offsetWidth - startWidth5Percent + 'px';
})
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>

<button id="button">Substract</button>
```

Comment: It works with offsetWidth! Unfortunately it's still substracting from current width, not the original.

Comment: @KolekcjaKolekcja I see, I updated it accordingly.

Comment: Great! It works just great but the last thing is that it stops on 5%, not 0%.

Comment: @KolekcjaKolekcja The first one converges but the second one successfully does it.

Answer (score 0):

How about just:

```js
substracktBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    container.offsetWidth = container.offsetWidth * 0.95
});
```

*Note: untested, not sure if JS requires the 'px' added at the end, but you get the gist.*

Comment: Unfortunately it sets with to 0px

Comment: Ive added `offsetWidth` instead. You need the property which sets the value

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the original width you need to save it to a variable first:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container")
var button = document.getElementById("button")

var containerOriginalWidth = container.clientWidth
var containerRatio = 1
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  containerRatio = containerRatio - 0.05
  container.style.width = (containerOriginalWidth * containerRatio)+'px'
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately it changes the width from 100% to 0px again

Comment: I see, let me modify my answer by using the clientWidth and clientHeight instead

Comment: @KolekcjaKolekcja I modified my answer assuming your container element id is "container" and button id is "button".

Answer (score 0):

- Use `offsetWidth` or `clientWidth` instead of `container.style.width` (which might be just an empty string)
- Add the missing `px` unit when using CSS `calc`

```js
const EL_btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
const EL_container = document.querySelector("#container");

EL_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  EL_container.style.width = `calc(${EL_container.offsetWidth}px - 5%)`
});
```

```css
#container {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" type="button">CLICK ME</button>
<div id="container">Container</div>
```

For a responsive era, my suggestion is to always set a width to the `%` unit instead:

```js
const EL_btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
const EL_container = document.querySelector("#container");

EL_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (!("_w" in EL_container)) EL_container._w = 100;
  EL_container._w = Math.max(0, EL_container._w - 5);
  EL_container.style.width = `${EL_container._w}%`;
});
```

```css
#container {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" type="button">CLICK ME</button>
<div id="container">Container</div>
```